# Concatenate results from batch in one file

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, concatenation

With some commands, I can get info from a specific agent. For example OS, architecture and version.

In Windows I want to put in a file every result from an agent list (resources.txt).

The result that I expect is a simple txt like:

```
Agent agentName - osName - osArch - osVersion
Agent agentName - osName - osArch - osVersion
Agent agentName - osName - osArch - osVersion
Agent agentName - osName - osArch - osVersion
```

But I can't figure how do it.

In my test I use the following

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion EnableExtensions

set resources=c:\resources.txt
set OS=C:\OS.txt
set arch=C:\arch.txt
set version=C:\version.txt

for /F "tokens=1" %%a in (%resources%) do (


echo --------------------- >> %OS%
echo|set /p=Resource: %%a - >> %OS% - >> %arch% - >> %version%

C:\command_to_run_and_get_OS_result %%a >> %OS%
C:\command_to_run_and_get_arch_result %%a >> %arch% 
C:\command_to_run_and_get_version_result %%a >> %version%
)
```

But with any success.-

Can you help me?

**Thanks!**

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What agent do you mean? What is in `resources.txt`?

Comment: @Emiliano Sturniolo Are you trying to query a number of different computers on LAN, using a fixed set of user agents? Or do you query just one PC with several agents to compare their results? In your reply always add username to page the asker.

Comment: @sambul35 Yes. I want to query different computers on LAN with internal command of one special application.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The agents are installed in several LAN machines and in the resoruces.txt file are the name of the agents.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering myself to post a solution for this.
A coworker shows some mercy for me and give me this solution.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion EnableExtensions

set resources=c:\resources.txt
set out=C:\out.txt

for /F "tokens=1" %%a in (%resources%) do ( 

 rem >> %version% -name sys.os.version

for /F "tokens=1" %%a in ('C:\command_to_run_and_get_OS_result %%a') do (set os=%%a)
for /F "tokens=1" %%a in ('C:\command_to_run_and_get_arch_result %%a') do (set arch=%%a)
for /F "tokens=1" %%a in ('C:\command_to_run_and_get_version_result %%a') do (set ver=%%a)

                           echo %%a ^| !os! ^| !arch! ^| !ver! >> %out%
```

So, with this code I can get the following results

```
agentName | osName | osArch | osVersion
agentName | osName | osArch | osVersion
agentName | osName | osArch | osVersion
agentName | osName | osArch | osVersion
agentName | osName | osArch | osVersion
```

Thanks @sambul35 and @MarkSetchell for your interest!